# Show the splash screen again in MVVMCross

Tags: c#, android, mvvmcross, splash-screen

I have an Android MVVMCross app that's going to ship on embedded hardware, and the app has a "System Reset" feature.  The feature does nothing more than clear all your settings to defaults and then persist them... simple and fast.  But the UX gurus would like it to reset back to the splash screen after the system reset, just as if the app has closed and restarted (mimicking a reboot).  Is there any way to do this without writing a custom splash screen and not using the MvxSplashScreenActivity base class?

My splash screen is the definition of simple.  Here's the complete C# code:

```
[Activity(MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
public class SplashScreenActivity : MvxSplashScreenActivity
{
    private ImageView _loadingView = null;
    private Timer _timer = null;

    public SplashScreenActivity() : base(Resource.Layout.Splash) { }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        _loadingView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.LoadingIndicatorImageView);
        _timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(UpdateLoadingImage), null, 500, 500);
    }

    protected void UpdateLoadingImage(object o)
    {
        RunOnUiThread(() => _loadingView.Rotation += 60);
    }
}
```